# How could I populate href of a list starting by a json?

Tags: json, ajax, href, src

I've got 3 videos in a folder and a json file with them, I would make a list near a player, and by clicking the list item I would play that specific video on that player. I've already made html and the function to get the elements to make the list, now I have to make the function to play each video

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="card col-sm-6">
        <div class="card-body container">
            <h5 class="card-title">Video</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Seleziona un video in elenco per visualizzarlo</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul id="listvideo" class="list-group list-group-flush border rounded">
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <video id="myVideo" src="files/assets/video/by_night.mp4" width="220"></video>
                    <button id="play" onclick="play()">Play</button>
                    <button id="stop" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
                  <!--  <span id="duration"></span> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

     

    
</section>

<script>

var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function play() {
  myVideo.play();
}
function stop(){
  myVideo.pause();
}


$(document)
     .ready(function() {
         $.ajax({
        url: 'files/assets/media.json',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
             success:function(data){
                 $.each(data.video,function(i,el){
                    var titolo = el.title;
                    console.log(titolo); 
                    $('#listvideo').append('<li class="list-group-item"><a class="choose" href="'+el+'">'+titolo+'</a></li>');
                 });
             }
         });   
            $('.choose').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var change = $(this).attr('href');
              


        });
```

});

```
</script>
```